# problem in datagrid mouseover and mouseout events.. in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have filled the asp.net datagrid in codebehind file. while binding i have used the datagrid onItemDataBound event to add onmouseover and onmouseout event that looks lik this..

protected void dataGridSavedQueris_OnItemDataBound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "dgRowHighlightOnWhenMouseOver(this,'" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "');");
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "dgRowHighlightOffWhenMouseOut (this,'" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "');");
    }        
}
```

now, it renders properly. i mean the dgrowHighlightOnWhenMouseOver and dgRowHighlightOffWhenMouseOut is assigned every row of the datagrid expect the header and footer.

in onmouseover and onmouseout function, I show the div with values of associating id.
what happening is whenever i move cursor one cell to another cell on the same row, it fires.

but, i need to fire the both events whenever I mouseover on the row not for cell..

how to do that?

thanks
r.e

Comment: you mean mouseout event is not fired?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to attach the mouseover/out on RowCreated rather than on ItemDataBound.

Something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "dgRowHighlightOnWhenMouseOver(this,'" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "');");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "dgRowHighlightOffWhenMouseOut(this,'" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "');");
  }
}
```

PS: I've not tried it out myself yet, so I'm not 100% sure :P

Comment: i have used only Asp.Net DataGrid not GridView. Eventhough I have tested with the GridView also.

but , I get the same result...

thanks
r.e

Comment: Ah, I missed out the DataGrid portion. Sorry mate.